# Are Firebase keys unique to the whole database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using `push()` Firebase creates a unique ID or key such as `-KKm9iRSax-scGn7m3Lb`.

According to the docs:

> The push() method generates a unique ID every time a new child is
>   added to the specified Firebase reference.

And:

> The unique ID generated by push() is based on a timestamp, so list
>   items are automatically ordered chronologically.

Is this ID or key unique to the whole database or only to the reference (like `/users`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase keys are part timestamp and part random characters. So while they should be unique across the whole database there is a small chance that two keys could end up being the same.

[Firebase blog: The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)

Comment: There is a trailing backslash in the URL. This is the correct one: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: So, to answer the original question more clearly, we can say that keys are equally unique whether they are under the same path or under different paths.